# perl grep replace vertical tabs with carriage returns

Tags: perl, grep

hopefully this one is easy, but it is evading me.

I'd like to replace vertical tabs (char 11) with carriage returns (char 13) in my file

(I'm exporting from Filemaker, which converts carriage returns in fields to vertical tabs)

I figured this would work, but it's not:

```
/usr/bin/perl -i -pe 's/\\011/\\013/g' foo.txt
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about tr///g instead of s///g?

Comment: For the record, I did not try tr. Removing one backslash also did not seem to work, but I am not ruling out operator error. Here's what did work:
    /usr/bin/perl -i -pe 's/\x{0B}/\r/g' foo.txt

Answer (score 2):

The double backslash in the regexp matches a single backslash in the input. You are replacing the literal 4-character string `\011` with the 4-character sequence `\013`. If your input contains actual vertical tabs, not the backslash-octal representation of them, you should undouble the backslashes in your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Or use tr:

```
mv foo.txt foo.txt.bak
tr '\v' '\r' <foo.txt.bak >foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to solutions other than perl, you can use sed:

```
sed -i "s/|/\n/" foo.txt
```